# How to set JSON file data as variable

Tags: python, json

so I am trying to load my JSON file's data to python, and then I want to use the JSON file data as a variable in python code, my way to do it is really just random guessing, can anyone here help me out?

Comment: `tmin = data['min_temperature']` use like this

Comment: What about searching a bit yourself first? :) You really expect this to be new problem, noone, esp. newbies, and noone, really posted, blogged, vblogged about that so fat at least once? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

you can use json lib to parse the string into dict.

```
import json
data = json.loads(string)
data[key]
```

Comment: he already use that, he just need to lear how to access that data  , `tmin = data['min_temperature']`

Answer (score 0):

doing `tmin = data['min_temperature']` will not work if you don't have that key.
Try `tmin = data.get('min_temperature', None)` where you will get None if the key is not present.